# Voltar para o fragment principal a partir de um botão

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-fragment

Olá, tenho um app que usa o `NavigationDrawer`, tenho um fragmento que possui um `AlertDialog`, e nele tenho dois botões enviar e cancelar, no cancelar desejo que volte para o fragment principal desejado.

Consegui fazer de um jeito que ele está voltando só que o título no toolbar fica o do antigo ainda. ai tenho que voltar novamente pra ele ficar o do fragment.

Meu `OnBackPressed` do `mainActivity`:

```
public void onBackPressed() {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //retornar o drawer
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            // retorna todos os fragments que estão em backStack
        } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            toolbar.setTitle("Expresso1002");
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
```

E a minha saida do botão cancelar:

```
btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_principal, new principal());
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque `toolbar.setTitle("Expresso1002");` no onCreateView do fargmento **principal()** e toda vez que esse fragmento for iniciado, ele se vai mudar o título da sua toolbar automaticamente.

Comment: Resolvi assim: `getActivity().setTitle("Expresso 1002");` , Só que ao voltar ele abre outra identica por cima ai tenho que voltar novamente.

Comment: Observe a sua transição entre os fragmentos. Ou seja, observe se você está usando ``fragmentTransaction.add`` ou ``fragmentTransaction.repleace``. Eu observei que você usa NavigationDrawer para suas transições. Por isso, recomendo usar sempre que possível usar ``fragmentTransaction.repleace``

Comment: Consegui resolver colocando: `getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);` abaixo do `fragmentTransaction.commit();`, vlw mano.